# How to add existing library written in C++ to android

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, ndk-build

If we have some library written in C++ (for example, https://github.com/gilbertchen/acrosync-library), how we can use it in android studio project? Do we need manually compile library into *.lib or *.so with `nmake` and after that write `jni` bridge for using the library? I couldn't find a detailed answer in google exactly for existing libraries. Maybe someone can create a test project with c-library and detailed step-by-step annotation?

Comment: yes you have to manually compile them to .so files

Comment: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/

Comment: See the Official documentation,,things are pretty clear there.
https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code